# Activity is sometimes blank when going back using popBackStack

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

[image: Even Android Studio Layout Inspector thinks that all our views are added to the layout. However width and height is 0dp for main_ll.]

I have an activity in Android which in its onCreate does this:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_detector);
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(activity_container, Fragment1.getInstance())
                    .commit();
}
```

Then `Fragment1` has this function: `goToFragment2()`

```
private void goToFragment2() {
 Fragment2 f2 = Fragment2.newInstance();
 FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 transaction.replace(activity_container, f2, Fragment2.class.getSimpleName());
 transaction.addToBackStack(null);
 transaction.commit();
}
```

which is used to go from `Fragment1` to `Fragment2` inside the activity. However, sometimes when I press the back button (or our own back arrow) which triggers a: `getFragmentManager().popBackStack()` then this happens:

The logs from the app looks completely normal but the view (activity) is completely empty. It is like the fragment isnt added to the activity. This is more likely to happen if I build my app in Android studio and install it and then open activity which starts f1, then go to f2, then go back, view is empty. If I play around with the app and then do it over and over the problem tends to go away.

I only see this behavior inside this specific Activity. This Activity can also launch `Fragment3` which launches `Fragment4` and when I go back from `Fragment4 to Fragment3` the same issue can occur. In any other Activity we use we **never** see this issue.

When we look in the Layout Inspector in Android Studio all our views are showing correctly in the list of different views. The width and height of all the views are however 0dp for. I never change those values explicitly but they just become 0dp in this case for some reason. And the container itself is just blank.

Comment: you are using addToBackStack(null) maybe that is the reason , try adding the backstack

Comment: What difference would that do? Unless I need to go back to a certain "level" there's no need to name the back stack entries from my understanding.